# Google (G Suit) Identity provider with nginx SAML2

Tags: nginx, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, shibboleth

You might heard about shibboleth and their great solutions as for Identity Provider (https://shibboleth.net/products/identity-provider.html) so is for Service Provider (e.g. nginx https://github.com/nginx-shib/nginx-http-shibboleth).

It's known that Google offers its own SAML2 IDP and we want to use it:

nginx needs to know what user from google is in order to proceed with website. Was possible to do that on **that tier** with shibboleth, but I have quite hard times finding solutions with Google.

Anybody has some ideas? Thank you!

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this project on [github](https://github.com/cloudflare/nginx-google-oauth)?

Looks like it is a SAML Auth provider for Google Apps.